# Grep a whole line based on the first time a term is found

Tags: regex, linux, command-line, grep

I would like to search through a rather large, sorted file (by the 4th, then the 3rd column), find the first time a new word is found in the 4th column and print out the whole line to a new file. 
For example, my file looks like this:

```
c1 23 1912 PE_1.7
c1 25 2334 PE_1.7
c1 59 2340 PE_1.7
c1 28 2342 PE_1.7
c1 30 2345 PE_1.7
c1 45 2346 PE_1.7
c1 23 2348 PA_11.4
c1 24 2352 PA_11.4
c1 57 2362 PA_123.2
c1 26 2372 DA_1.5
```

And I would hope the new file would look like this:

```
c1 23 1912 PE_1.7
c1 23 2348 PA_11.4
c1 57 2362 PA_123.2
c1 26 2372 DA_1.5
```

I am rotten with regex but I was thinking something along these lines:

```
grep \t.[_].[\.]$
```

Is there a good way to do this type of grep, or am I barking up the wrong tree, so to speak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
uniq --skip-fields=3 input.txt
```

Yields:

```
c1 23 1912 PE_1.7
c1 23 2348 PA_11.4
c1 57 2362 PA_123.2
c1 26 2372 DA_1.5
```

Comment: Chosen because it lets me do what I need to, without the need for sticky regex

Answer (score 1):

try this awk one-liner:

```
awk 'p!=$4{print;p=$4}' file > newFile
```

Comment: @fedorqui fyi `sorted file (by the 4th, then the 3rd column)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ awk '!x[$4]++' file
c1 23 1912 PE_1.7
c1 23 2348 PA_11.4
c1 57 2362 PA_123.2
c1 26 2372 DA_1.5
```

Comment: Could you explain the regex you chose? As I mentioned, I am really rotten at it and I hope to learn from what you did.

Comment: @user2076476 It's a concise way of saying what is mentioned in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19119562/2235132) answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to use awk:

```
awk '!($4 in a) {a[$4]; print}' file
c1 23 1912 PE_1.7
c1 23 2348 PA_11.4
c1 57 2362 PA_123.2
c1 26 2372 DA_1.5
```

Comment: Could you explain the regex you chose? As I mentioned, I am really rotten at it and I hope to learn from what you did.